# Generate tooltip through * symbol

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have the following PHP code:

```
function word_filter()
{
$tt_tijdelijke = '';
$tt_gestoffeerd = '';
$tt_gemeubileerd = '';

str_replace('tijdelijke', '<span class="incexc-single" tooltip="'.$tt_tijdelijke.'">tijdelijke</span>');
str_replace('gestoffeerd', '<span class="incexc-single" tooltip="'.$tt_gestoffeerd.'">gestoffeerd</span>');
str_replace('gemeubileerd', '<span class="incexc-single" tooltip="'.$tt_gemeubileerd.'">gemeubileerd</span>');
return true;
}
add_filter('wordfilter','word_filter');
```

I need this to run on every page in the website, replacing all the words with the same word, but inserted in a span. Doing so will allow a tooltip to appear when I mouse over the word.

The mouseover and tooltip already work, but I can't figure out how to get the replace to work on all pages.

How can I best call this function without causing too much page load?

Comment: What do you mean by "a word"? You need an element that JQuery recognizes, such as a span or a div. Otherwise you would have nothing that JQuery could apply any tooltip magic to.

Comment: @FlorianF. I've looked on the internet how to detect symbols on pages but I can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use javascript split. the code will alert the text, but you can change that and use it for tooltip.

```
var txt = 'Word*tooltip';
alert(txt.split("*")[1]);
```

Comment: How would I apply this to the entire page, and not just a single string?

Comment: Just create a javascript function. And onmouse over of the elements you can call it. please create a jsfiddle showing what exactly you mean if I am missing anything.

Comment: I already have that mouseover and tooltip, what I need is to replace a word with the same word, but in html so it has the tooltip.

Comment: create a jsfiddle pls.

Comment: I would if I could. I can make one if I manage to solve the problem though.